# recorrer coleccion laravel 8 en la vista

Tags: laravel

Hola buenas les cuento esta  es una coleccion con la variable $producto_array_sesion que se pasa a la vista mediante compact
le e puesto en el controler esto

```
   $array = collect($producto_array);
   $array_agregado=$array->push($producto_array);
   $producto_array_sesion=$array_agregado;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

agrego al blade de esta forma

```
 <tbody>

  @php ($cont_compra=0)
    @if($producto_array_sesion)
    @foreach($producto_array_sesion as $ingreso)
@foreach($ingreso as $llave=>$Producto_compra)   
    <tr>
<td class="text-center">{{$cont_compra}}</td>
<td class="text-center">{{$Producto_compra['id_producto_compra']}}</td>
```

```
      <input type="text" id="precio_{{$cont_compra}}"  name ="precio_[]" class="input-precio 
 form-control" onchange="calculate(),validateprecio(this)" placeholder="precio de compra 
   unitario" required="" ></td>     
      <td class="text-center"> <label class="subtotal"  for="">0</label>
      </td>
      
      <td>
  <a href="{{ route('compras.verCarrito.eliminar',$Producto_compra['id_producto_compra']) }}" 
 id="eliminar" class="redondo btn btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a>          

       </td>
    </tr>
    @php($cont_compra++)
    @endforeach
    @endforeach
    @endif
    
</tbody>
```

producto_array es solo de un producto, un array simple, como seria el codigo entonces , lo que deseo es al presionar el boton de la vista esta coleccion valla creciendo de uno en uno(los objetos)

tambien tengo esto que la diferencia q en vez de un array es una collect dentro de otra

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
como la recorreria
o mas bien esta bien mi idea de agregarlo mediante un boton un objeto se agrega a la coleccion y esta va creciendo

ayuda porfavor

Comment: Creo que le falta un poco más de contexto a tu pregunta para poder ayudarte

Comment: Dandole un vista rapida, probablemente `$array = collect($producto_array);` no es lo que crees. Cual es el valor de `$producto_array`? Tiene pinta de que son las propiedades de un solo producto, y no un array de productos

Comment: chuta, producto_array es solo de un producto, un array simple, como seria el codigo entonces , lo que deseo es al presionar el boton de la vista esta coleccion valla creciendo de uno en uno(los objetos)